# Design a database with a lot of new data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Im new to database design and need some guidance.
A lot of new data is inserted to my database throughout the day. (100k rows per day)
The data is never modified or deleted once it has been inserted.
How can I optimize this database for retrieval speed?

My ideas

- Create two databases (and possible on different hard drives) and merge the two at night when traffic is low
- Create some special indexes...

Your recommendation is highly appreciated.

UPDATE:
My database only has a single table.

Comment: Questions: is the data held indefinitely?  Are you reporting on individual records, or aggregating the data when reporting over a period of time? Is all data reported against or just the most recent?  How is data inserted - in individual transactions or via bulk load?

Comment: data is held indefinitely. an individual row or 50 rows can be retrieved from the database based a the primary key (Int) ordered by insertion time (DateTime) or Title (NVarChar) or Priority (Int). Data is inserted in individual transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tip I can give which all big sites use to speed up there website is:

### CACHE CACHE CACHE

use [redis](http://antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html)/[memcached](http://memcached.org/) to cache your data! Because memory is (blazingly)fast and disc I/O is expensive.

### Queue writes

Also for extra performance you could queue up the writes in memory for a little while before flushing them to disc -> writting them to SQL database. Off course then you have the risk off losing data if you keep it in memory and your computer crashes or has power failure or something

### Context missing

Also I don't think you gave us much context!

What I think is missing is:

1. architecture.

   1. What kind of server are you having VPS/shared hosting.
   2. What kind of Operating system does it have linux/windows/macosx
   3. computer specifics like how much memory available, cpu etc.
2. a find your definition of data a bit vague. Could you not attach a diagram or something which explains your domain a little bit. For example something like [image]

   this using http://yuml.me/

Comment: what would you like to know more about?

Comment: dedicated hosting. window server 2008 r2. sql server 2008 r2. 8gb of ram.

Comment: Your hosting kind screws you over because you need a posix like system to install systems like redis/memcached/beanstalkd. I would advice you to install such system instead. But you have more than enough RAM which is a good thing!

Comment: Before looking at this though, if your table has a lot of columns you may need to look at database normalisation (breaking down your one table into several logically related tables) By doing this you may be able to reduce a lot of data duplication.

Answer (score 2):

100k/day is actually fairly low. 3M/month, 40M/year. You can store 10 years archive and not reach 1B rows.

The most important thing to choose in your design will be the clustered key(s). You need to make sure that they are narrow and can serve all the queries your application will normally use. Any query that will end up in table scan will completely trash your memory by fetching in the entire table. So, no surprises there, your driving factor in your design is the actual load you'll have: exactly what queries will you be running.

A common problem (more often neglected than not) with any high insert rate is that eventually every row inserted will have to be deleted. Not acknowledging this is a pipe dream. The proper strategy depends on many factors, but probably the best bet is on a sliding window partitioning scheme. See [How to Implement an Automatic Sliding Window in a Partitioned Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). This cannot be some afterthought, the choice for how to *remove* data will permeate every aspect of your design and you better start making a strategy now.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are way to general. For MS SQL server 100k (more or less "normal") records per days should not be a problem, if you have decent hardware. Obviously you want to write fast to the database, but you ask for optimization for retrieval performance. That does not match very well! ;-) Tuning a database is a special skill on its own. So you will never get the general answer you would like to have.

Comment: I want to design it to handle 10x the traffic.